# How can I identify gaps in polylines and polylines with more than one end point using ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, topology

I have a multipart polyline shapefile containing a large number of lines, some of which are broken by gaps and some of which have more than one start and end (by mistake - see attached). I need to have a multipart shapefile output, which contains only unbroken lines with one start and one end. Is there a way to identify these errors (can't seem to do it with the the topology rules in Arc)?

Once identified they are easy to fix manually.

Comment: attachment is not visible..can you post it to dropbox or somewhere else if you can't add image here?

Answer (score 4):

If the polylines are unbroken then they should only be a single part.  You could use Python to create a to loop through each record in the shapefile and get the part count of each feature.  If the part count is greater than 1 then the feature should have multiple start and end points or be disconnected.

**UPDATE:**

```
import arcpy

inputSHP = r"path/to/input/shapefile"
outputSHP = r"path/to/output/shapefile" # This shapefile should already be created with all the properties of the input shapefile (use input shapefile as a template)

fields = arcpy.ListFields(inputSHP) # This gets all the fields in the input shapefile into a python list

outrows = arcpy.InsertCursor(outputSHP) # This allows you to insert features into the output shapefile

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inputSHP) # This reads each feature in the input shapefile one at a time

for row in rows: # Loop through each feature in the input shapefile

    if row.SHAPE.partCount == 1: # Determine if geometry has more than one part

        newrow = outrows.newRow() # Create new feature in output shapefile

        for field in fields: # Loop through fields in input shapefile (these should be exactly the same as in the output shapefile)

            newrow.setValue(field.name, row.getValue(field.name) # Set the value of each field in the output shapefile feature to that field in the of the input shapefile feature

        outrows.insertRow(newrow) # Save the new feature into the output shapefile

        del newrow # Memory management (delete the new row object)

    del row # Memory management (delete the input row object)
del rows, outrows # Memory management (delete the cursor objects)
```

Comment: Thank you - it sounds as though that would do it. Unfortunately I have almost no experience with Python. Do you know of anywhere I could find a similar example script?

Comment: I added a code example to get you started.  Check out the ArcPy Site Package and the ArcGIS Python help to get some more background.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/What_is_Python/002z00000001000000/

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I would use:
add field TmpID as long
calculate tmpID = Objectid (to preserve the ObjectID)
run tool MultipartToSinglepart
run tool UnsplitLine
run tool Frequency on tmpID (this produces a feature count for each tmpID)
join the frequency table to your polylines (join on polyline.objectid = frequency.tmpid)
select "Frequency" > 1